# Help identifying a photodiode pre-amp PCB

Tags: pcb, photodiode, preamp

Recently I found this PCB in a electronics junk bin. It's said that it's a photodiode preamp, but I was not able to find the datasheet or any information about the board.

[image: Front]

[image: Back]
Since the PCB looks neatly designed and put together I wanted to know where this PCB could have been used for.

Would also be interesting to find the IC's that are missing and test the functionality.

Comment: It's probably a custom design that was included in a product at one point, so there is most likely no datasheet. It looks like it was made by [DCI](http://www.dci.ca/), a company that designs and builds custom high-performance analog boards.

Comment: Photodiode preamp boards of this age are typically not something that's going to be generically commercially available. As Caleb said, this looks like a custom board for a company. there will be no public data available, as well as even the company itself probably has nothing more than a schematic.

Comment: @MadHatter Not to mention the fact that the schematic is probably protected by some kind of non-disclosure agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Board PN listed under a [Chinese](http://www.xiamenjiyang.com/wap/products_show.asp?id=1199) website, for industrial products.

There was just a huge list of board part numbers only. Further info is proprietary.

Here is their [testimonial](http://www.xiamenjiyang.com/wap/news_show.asp?id=716) translated in part below, using S3.translator in Firefox.

*,...
Well-known domestic listed companies Shuangliang energy-saving and environmental protection system known as China Co., Ltd. in the industry "Oscar" awards competitions in the titles and captured the industry the only win of the enterprise.

　　In the list of national award-winning business only 13 years, many of them Chinese Academy of Launch Vehicle Technology and other people carrying the pride and dreams of space science and technology enterprise, together with Shuangliang in the column, not a coincidence. Shuangliang was the first time the introduction of the civil aerospace engineering method of leak detection equipment manufacturing, to increase the vacuum bromine cooler to unprecedented heights, the whole crew leak rate a full four orders of magnitude lower than the Japanese Industrial Standard, beat from the performance to sophisticated known Japanese counterparts.*

My guess is you got 1 good 1MHz channel already with high gain and low noise.  Maybe even AGC.

- AD848  High Speed, Low Power 175MHz Monolithic Op Amp (1)  Missing 1 in socket ??
- TL072  Low-Noise JFET-Input Dual (2)  3MHz Operational Amplifiers
- OL275  Dual Bipolar/JFET, 9MHz  Audio Operational Amplifier (2 duals)
- AD8574 8-Bit Buffered Multiplying DAC  1MHz ? maybe  (2)

For differential high speed Analog and digital channel, 1sensor
  Differential mode PD? hmmm anyone?

Vintage US 1994 design with 8 digit part numbers from some large OEM with low noise TIA S/N 11 --- custom from elsewhere like Silicon Valley. I used to do stuff like this in the 80's 90's.

SIngle V+ in 24V with dual split supply for Analog and 5V ADC from ferrite DCDC reg.  might be possible to hot power externally. Then observe analog outputs on TP turrets.

Or maybe you find out it is Scintillator product glass window contaminant counter or maybe Pigs will fly.
[image]